# Android ImageButton setMaxheight not having effect

Tags: android, height, imagebutton, image-scaling

I use a table layout to layout buttons using weights, the buttons get 0dip size or wrap_content and so they expand by their weight.

I'm trying to convert a button to ImageButton and set the image to be in the button size and not expand it.

I let the button get created and get it's size and then I assign the image and limit it's height using ImageButton.setMaxHeight();

```
final ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonOptions);
    ib.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            final int height = ib.getHeight();
            ib.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            ib.setMaxHeight(5); // or height    
            ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.options);

        }});
```

The images is being drawn in it's original size, thus expanding the button...
setMaxHeight() is not limiting the image height/width. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved it using

```
ib.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewTreeObserver observer = ib.getViewTreeObserver();
observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
//here you can get height and set height
}
```

Not sure but try it.It may help you.

Comment: same result, the button grows to the size of the image

Comment: @aviran try ib.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.options); instead of ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.options);

Answer (score 0):

setMaxHeight() is for the imagebutton and not for the image in it.

Try,

```
ib.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

Comment: same result, the button grows to the size of the image

Comment: Try setting layout width and height like android:layout_width="60dp"
         android:layout_height="60dp"